# How to write a while loop to input prices and then stops when user inputs 0

Tags: python, list, if-statement, input, while-loop

I need to write a short code that the user can input prices from a shopping trip and when the user input 0 the while loop will stop.  After it stops, I need to have an else statement to show the total number of items, average price, and total price.

I am new to programming and I am starting off in python.  Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
price = float
items = float
while price < 0:
    items = price
    price = input("Please enter prices of items:")

else:
    avg = float(sum(items) / len(items))
    print('Number of items purchased:', len(items))
    print('Average price of items: $', avg)
    print('Total price of purchased items: $', sum(items))
```

**while price < 0:**

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'int'

Comment: not gonna spoonfeed.. 
but you will need to use `break` in while loop to break the loop when user enters 0...
and after that, you can print the statements

Comment: search for usage of `break` and try it on console.. I am sure you will figure out how to use it in current problem

Comment: I really appreciate the help. So using the break is what will allow it to move on from the while loop when a 0 is entered. Thanks everyone.

Comment: What is `price = float` supposed to mean? `float` is a type, not a number.

Comment: Use `while True:` to loop until you use `break` inside the loop.

Comment: If you want to use `sum(items)` and `len(items)` then `items` should be a list.

Comment: You should get the price, then append it to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

First things first, your error message:

```
while price < 0: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'int'
```

The first bit of the error is telling you the code that's causing the problem; the compiler doesn't like `while price < 0:`. Why not? That's the second bit of the message: you can't compare a `type` to an `int`. So your `price` variable is a type, rather than a number (int or float) which doesn't sound right.

So how do we declare variables properly in python? We don't need to explicitly tell the interpreter what type of variable they are, it'll work it out for itself. For example these are different variable declarations that all work:

```
price = 0.123 // this declares a float
name = 'BoatingPuppy' // this declares a string
favourites = ['apples','pears','diamonds'] // and this declares a list
```

They would all work, whereas `price = float` is not declaring a new float variable.

Now how about your while loop? At the moment you're entering your loop if `price` is less than 0 but you've not got a value for price yet, so that's not going to work. You've also got an `else` below your `while` loop, but that's not how `while` loops work, do you want an `if` statement there instead? The [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) has lots of information about flow control.

How about something like this:

```
prices = []

while True:
    price = float(input('Enter price of '+item+': ')
    if price = 0:
        break
    else:
        prices.append(price)

total_price = prices.sum()
avg_price = total_price/len(prices)

print('Total price: ', end='')
print(total_price)
print('Average price: ', end='')
print(avg_price)]
```

Let's go through this to see what it's doing.

```
prices = []
```

First we've made an empty list to store all of the prices.

```
while True:
    price = float(input('Enter price of '+item+': ')
    if price = 0:
        break
    else:
        prices.append(price)
```

Next we're using a `while` loop. While loops evaluate the statement after `while` in order to decide whether it should run, so if we set that as `True` then it'll run forever (or until we `break` out of it).

Every time that `while` loop runs it'll ask the user for a price, use an `if` statement to check if the price is 0, and break out of the `while` loop if it is or add the value to the list `prices` if it isn't.

```
total_price = prices.sum()
avg_price = total_price/len(prices)
```

Next we're calculating the total price of all the items in the `prices` list, and using this to work out the average price by dividing the total by the number of items in the list.

```
print('Total price: ', end='')
print(total_price)
print('Average price: ', end='')
print(avg_price)]
```

Finally we're printing these for the user.